# Visual Studio Subscription

Tags: msdn, subscription

I've received a quote for Microsoft MSDN subscription (VSProwMSDN ALNG LicSAPk OLP NL Qlfd) for $1,684. I believe has 2 years upgrades.

I've also found this site:  http://www.microsoftstore.com.au/shop/en-AU/Microsoft/Visual-Studio-Professional-2010-Upgrade   that has 1 year of MSDN Essentials access for $945.00.

In the "Before you buy" section on that page it says:
"To qualify for upgrade pricing, you must be a licensed user of one of the following products: an earlier version of Microsoft Visual Studio, or any other developer tool (including free developer tools, such as Visual Studio Express Editions or Eclipse).

Visual Studio 2010 Professional includes a 12-month MSDN Essentials subscription. MSDN Essentials gives you access to core Microsoft platforms: Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows Server 2008 Enterprise R2, and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Datacenter R2."

What is the better value product? I am doing development and would probably consider doing a longer subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the better value is the two year Microsoft MSDN subscription (VSProwMSDN ALNG LicSAPk OLP NL Qlfd).

As you say, it's open business and lasts for 2 years.

Check out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx

Plus, even without the benefit of not having to worry about the 'upgrade' version, it's cheaper - $842 per year vs. $945 for one year with limitations.